# SQL Substring and Charindex

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have 111-1001-0000-0000 this record in one column and 453200-0000-000 in second column

I want output as 111-1001-0000-453200-0000-0000-000

That means 111-1001-0000 from 1st column and 453200 from 2nd column and again 0000 from 1st column and 0000-000
from 2nd column

I tried below query but getting 111-1001-453200-0000-0000-000.

-0000 is missing from 1st column

```
Declare @1stcolumn nvarchar(30),@2ndcolumn nvarchar(30)

set @1stcolumn='111-1001-0000-0000'
            
set @2ndcolumn='453200-0000-000' 

select substring(@1stcolumn,1,charindex(right(@1stcolumn,charindex('-',reverse(@1stcolumn))),@1stcolumn))
+substring(@2ndcolumn,1,charindex('-',@2ndcolumn))+reverse(substring(reverse(@1stcolumn),0,charindex('-',reverse(@1stcolumn))))
+'-'+substring(@2ndcolumn,charindex('-',@2ndcolumn)+1,len(@2ndcolumn))
```

Answer (score 2):

find the position where to split column 1 and column2. Use `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` to split the string and then concatenate back in the order that you want

```
; with tbl as
(
    select  col1 = @1stcolumn, col2 = @2ndcolumn
)
select  *,
        c1.s1 + '-' + c2.s1 + '-' +c1.s2 + '-' + c2.s2
from    tbl t
        cross apply
        (
            select  s1 = left(col1, p - 1),
                    s2 = right(col1, len(col1) - p)
            from    (
                        -- find the position of 3rd '-' by cascading charindex
                        select  p = charindex('-', col1, 
                                         charindex('-', col1, 
                                             charindex('-', col1) + 1) + 1)
                    ) p
        ) c1
        cross apply
        (
            select  s1 = left(col2, p - 1),
                    s2 = right(col2, len(col2) - p)
            from    (
                        select  p = charindex('-', col2)
                    ) p
        ) c2
```

Answer (score 0):

A little modification in first `substring`. To get correct length I used `LEN` .

```
select substring(@1stcolumn,1,(Len(@1stcolumn) - charindex('- ',REVERSE(@1stcolumn)) + 1))
+substring(@2ndcolumn,1,charindex('-',@2ndcolumn))
+reverse(substring(reverse(@1stcolumn),0,charindex('-',reverse(@1stcolumn))))
+'-'+substring(@2ndcolumn,charindex('-',@2ndcolumn)+1,len(@2ndcolumn))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do with with `PARSENAME` as it's quite concise then:

```sql
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT '111-1001-0000-0000' AS Column1,
           '453200-0000-000' AS Column2)
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-',PN.C1P1,PN.C1P2,PN.C1P3,PN.C2P1,PN.C1P4,PN.C2P2,PN.C2P3) AS NewString
FROM YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(YT.Column1,'-','.'),REPLACE(YT.Column2,'-','.')))R(Column1,Column2)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PARSENAME(R.Column1,4),PARSENAME(R.Column1,3),PARSENAME(R.Column1,2),PARSENAME(R.Column1,1),PARSENAME(R.Column2,3),PARSENAME(R.Column2,2),PARSENAME(R.Column2,1)))PN(C1P1,C1P2,C1P3,C1P4,C2P1,C2P2,C2P3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
  test AS
(
select '111-1001-0000-0000' as col1, '453200-0000-000' as col2
)
,cte as
(
select 
       col1,
       col2,
       substring
                          (
                          col1,
                          0,
                          len(col1)-charindex('-',reverse(col1))
                          ) as part1,
        substring
                          (
                          col2,
                          0,
                          len(col2)-charindex('-',col2) - 1
                          ) as part2
from test
),
cte2 as
(
select 
        part1,
        part2,
        substring
                          (
                          reverse(col1),
                          0,
                          charindex('-',reverse(col1))
                          ) as part3,
        substring
                          (
                          col2,
                          charindex('-',col2)+1,
                          len(col2)-charindex('-',col2)+1
                          ) as part4
from cte
)
select part1+'-'+part2+'-'+part3+'-'+part4
from cte2
```